# Error while comparing string after transforming from datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I am converting datetime to string and then comparing it with string from stdout.read from a file. But the "==" comparision fails.

Below is my code:

```
date_input = datetime.datetime.now()
dat = date_input.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

command = 'echo %s > /media/mmcblk0p1/testCard.txt' %dat
try:
    stdin, stdout, stderr = self._sshclient.exec_command(command,timeout=10)
    command = 'cat /media/mmcblk0p1/testCard.txt'
    try:
        stdin, stdout, stderr = self._sshclient.exec_command(command, timeout=10)
        date_output = stdout.read().decode(encoding='UTF-8')
        self.logger.debug("dat=%s date_output=%s ",dat,date_output)

        if(date_output == dat):    #FAILS
            self.logger.debug("read from file successful")
        else:
            self.logger.debug("read from file unsucessful")
    except:
        self.logger.exception('%s %s error, readtimeout',
                              ip, self.__class__.__name__)
        self.add_response("read error/timeout")
except :
    self.logger.exception('%s %s error, writetimeout',
                          ip, self.__class__.__name__)
    self.add_response("write error/timeout")
```

### Output

```
dat=2016-09-06 15:49:49.104030 date_output=2016-09-06 15:49:49.104030
read from file unsucessful
dat=2016-09-06 15:49:49.237551 date_output=2016-09-06 15:49:49.237551
read from file unsucessful
```

I am unable to figure out the comparision failure, it prints "read from file unsuccessful" Is it for the stdout.read() or datetime.

NOTE: There is no exception in this code, and the values are same if i use print method also.

Any solution is welcome

Comment: Check the length of both of them and see if they differ? Maybe there are some hidden characters.

Comment: can you check there are no spaces or newlines at the end of the strings `date_output=\`%s\`` or `len(date_output)` or have a look at [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`echo`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) adds a new line character to the end of its output, therefore the date is written to `/media/mmcblk0p1/testCard.txt` with a trailing new line. Either strip it off when you read it back in, or use the `-n` option to `echo` to suppress the new line on output like this:

```
command = 'echo -n %s > /media/mmcblk0p1/testCard.txt' %dat
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a
'2016-09-06 15:49:49.104030'
>>> b
u'2016-09-06 15:49:49.104030'
>>> a == b
True
>>> b = b + "\n"
>>> a == b
False
```

There could be whitespace characters in one of your strings, remove them using .strip()

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `.strip()`

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm

```
Example:
if(date_output.strip() == dat.strip()):
```

If there are any whitespace characters on either end of the string (which i think there are) then .strip() takes them out and we can compare the strings without the whitespace characters.

Comment: Why is this better than `date_output == dat`?

Comment: If there are any whitespace characters on either end of the string (which i think there are) then .strip() takes them out and we can compare the strings without the whitespace characters.

Comment: Maybe put that in your answer.